# Html input date when select same date

Tags: javascript, html

I have question,

If I have a html element like this:

```
<input type="date" onchange="func(this)" value="2022-05-16">
```

It works fine, when you select a different date, if I select 2022-05-16, the func() is not calling, I know seems the onchange only trigger when the date is different(onchange), but if I want to trigger when I select 2022-05-16, same as original date, How I can set it up correctly? Here I do not want to change it to 2022-05-15, then change back to 2022-05-16, I want one click only to tigger my func() here.

Comment: on top of your 'func()' declaration you can take orginal value via dom element selection and compare it new ones

Comment: @bunyaminkirmizi, can you provide more info of this? I am new to this, for what I found, if the date is same as the current value, it does not even trigger a call to func.

Answer (score 0):

try `oninput`:

```
<input type="date" oninput="func(this)" value="2022-05-16">
```

Comment: It seems oninput, if select  2022-05-16, it wont trigger the func.